# SQL: Select where doesnt exist in other table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the same name in each table however it is still selecting it from the ingredients table even though the exact name is in the ingredients_master table. Any ideas why?

```
SELECT
    `ingredients`.`id`,
    `ingredients`.`name` 
FROM
    `ingredients` 
WHERE
    `ingredients`.`name` LIKE '%makers%' ESCAPE '!' 
    OR `ingredients`.`name` LIKE '%jack%' ESCAPE '!' 
    OR `ingredients`.`name` LIKE '%hennesey%' ESCAPE '!' 
    OR `ingredients`.`name` LIKE '%bourbon%' ESCAPE '!' 
    OR `ingredients`.`name` LIKE '%RYE%' ESCAPE '!' 
    AND NOT EXISTS ( 
        SELECT * FROM ingredients_master WHERE ingredients.NAME = ingredients_master.NAME 
    ) 
GROUP BY
    `ingredients`.`name`
```

Comment: Try to use parentheses for all the 'Or' condition, and then use not exists outside of parentheses.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is related to the way you are using `AND` and `OR` operators : `AND` has higher prescendence than `OR`, so this :

```
WHERE
    `ingredients`.`name` LIKE '%makers%' ESCAPE '!' 
    OR `ingredients`.`name` LIKE '%jack%' ESCAPE '!' 
    OR `ingredients`.`name` LIKE '%hennesey%' ESCAPE '!' 
    OR `ingredients`.`name` LIKE '%bourbon%' ESCAPE '!' 
    OR `ingredients`.`name` LIKE '%RYE%' ESCAPE '!' 
    AND NOT EXISTS ( 
        SELECT * FROM ingredients_master WHERE ingredients.NAME = ingredients_master.NAME 
    )
```

Is actually equivalent to :

```
WHERE
    `ingredients`.`name` LIKE '%makers%' ESCAPE '!' 
    OR `ingredients`.`name` LIKE '%jack%' ESCAPE '!' 
    OR `ingredients`.`name` LIKE '%hennesey%' ESCAPE '!' 
    OR `ingredients`.`name` LIKE '%bourbon%' ESCAPE '!' 
    OR (
        `ingredients`.`name` LIKE '%RYE%' ESCAPE '!' 
        AND NOT EXISTS ( 
            SELECT * FROM ingredients_master WHERE ingredients.NAME = ingredients_master.NAME 
        ) 
    )
```

So if any of the first `OR`ed conditions is true, the result is true, not matter the result of the `NOT EXIST` condition.

You probably want :

```
WHERE
    (
        `ingredients`.`name` LIKE '%makers%' ESCAPE '!' 
        OR `ingredients`.`name` LIKE '%jack%' ESCAPE '!' 
        OR `ingredients`.`name` LIKE '%hennesey%' ESCAPE '!' 
        OR `ingredients`.`name` LIKE '%bourbon%' ESCAPE '!' 
        OR `ingredients`.`name` LIKE '%RYE%' ESCAPE '!' 
    )
    AND NOT EXISTS ( 
        SELECT * FROM ingredients_master WHERE ingredients.NAME = ingredients_master.NAME 
    )
```

Comment: nice catch. One question though: Do you think that the use of `not in()` will serve better purpose here, specially performance wise?

Comment: @HarshilDoshi : hard to tell without seeing the whole picture... usually `NOT EXISTS` is the correct approach to implement kind of requirement.

Comment: @HarshilDoshi - Avoid `NOT IN (<subquery>)`. It not only has a bad performance, but you might get unexpected results, when NULLs are involved. Just run this simple query: `select 1 not in (2,3, null)`